# Is it possible to prevent a ReplicaSet from scaling up/down?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Basically, I'm asking if ReplicaSets have something simillar to the `suspend: "true"` option for CronJobs but I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: just specify replicaSet value to 1 it should fix your problem

Comment: @NaveenKulkarni I have a python script that scales up my replicasets from 0 to 1 if it detects traffic. I want to somehow disable those replicasets so that the scale up process does not happen. Is this possible?

Comment: You should have a replicaSet count as at least 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the official Kubernetes doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/#replicaset-as-a-horizontal-pod-autoscaler-target)

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: frontend-scaler
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: frontend
  minReplicas: 3
  maxReplicas: 3
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 50
```

A quick and easy workaround your problem is to have minReplicas and maxReplicas to the same amount.

Also for measuring traffic is better to use prometheus-operator and grafana, you can install them through Helm without any effort or problems.

That way you can achieve better results in scaling up and down

Answer (score 2):

There is no out of box support. But there might be a way to do that using combination of 'kind: PodDisruptionBudget' and 'kind: ResourceQuota'. i havent tried it though